# Solving one quadratic equals another

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratics

So say we have two quadratic equations, both in $ax^2+bx+x$ format.
And they equal one another: $4x^2+5x+7=5x^2+14x-6$
How would you solve it?

Comment: group like terms on both sides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can move all Terms to one side:
at first $$-4x^2$$
then $$-5x$$ and $$-7$$
and we get
$$0=x^2+9x-13$$
can you solve this equation?